# Invoking abilities not needed in order to charge Net Mercur

Tags: android-netrunner

Is the Runner allowed to invoke abilities from cards which they do not need in order to add a credit to Net Mercur?

For example, let's say the Runner uses their last click to run on Archives (which is unprotected say) - during this run, can they spend a credit from a Stealth card which they do not need to do for any other reason than to add a credit to Net Mercur?

I'm assuming the answer is yes, but answers using any reference material to support their statements would be appreciated.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can trigger Net Mercur off of itself.

Comment: True, as long as they are spent on *something*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. According to the [official FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/aa/d3/aad35e6c-afdb-4de4-b034-ec5b5b748106/adn_faq_v312.pdf), "a player can only trigger an action or ability if it has the potential to change the game state." But the FAQ also states:

> The Runner can boost the strength of his icebreakers outside of an encounter with a piece of ice.

So, assuming you have a source of stealth credits and an icebreaker that can have its strength boosted, then you can do so even if it's not being used to interact with any ice. That would trigger Net Mercur's ability.

*Edit*:
For further clarification, it must be noted that Net Mercur's ability can only be triggered during a run.

Comment: Boosting ice is specifically called out as something you can do as a paid ability, regardless of whether that ice is being used, so yes that counts as changing the game state. Spending a click and 2 credits to remove a tag when you have no tags, for example, would count as not changing the game state

Comment: The change in icebreaker strength is a change in game state, the idea of that rule is the cost cannot be the only thing that changes, the effect must do something, without regards to any other effects it would trigger (like mercur's ability) Since the effect of paying to boost ice breakers is that breaker is temporarily stronger, that causes a change in game state.